# Find characters in a line which is surrounded by whitespace in bash using egrep

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I have a file which looks likes this :

```
Arjun
A
   A
 A
sdsdA
AA
AAA
```

I want to find lines that contain an A which is surrounded by white space on both sides.Hence the desired output for this would be :

```
   A
 A
```

Only lines 3 and 4 should come in the output.I tried the following:

```
egrep '(^|\s)A($|\s)' filename
```

and got this in output:

```
A
   A
 A
```

It somehow is matching the second line as well which starts with a solitary A. How do i avoid that ?

Comment: but ` A` isn't followed by a space character. Could you explain clearly?

Comment: Why grep `^` and `$` then? `egrep '\sA\s' filename` should do, no?

Comment: yeah..that works..i feel so foolish :-P

Comment: you might want to post that as an answer so that I can accept it..

Comment: @Amistad please add a space next to the `A`, so that you get the desired output..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have an actual space on either side of the 2nd & 3rd "  A  " lines, and not ending in A, then either of these should work, with grep or egrep, matching only a space character, A, space character:

```
grep " A " filename
grep ' A ' filename
```

Or using a character class:

```
grep '[[:space:]]A[[:space:]]' filename
```

But the `[[:space:]]` class maybe *should* match all "whitespace" too (tab, **newline**, vertical tab, form feed, carriage return, and space) according to [GNU.org's grep manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Character-Classes-and-Bracket-Expressions.html), but it doesn't seem to match a newline for my `grep (GNU grep) 2.16`, unless an A then the end of a line isn't a newline.

Apparently [GNU.org tells me](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/The-Backslash-Character-and-Special-Expressions.html#The-Backslash-Character-and-Special-Expressions) that `‘\s’`  Matches whitespace, it is a synonym for `[[:space:]]`

So this one with `[[:blank:]]` should match only space or tab:

```
grep '[[:blank:]]A[[:blank:]]' filename
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't want `A` to start or finish, you don't need the `^` and the `$`:

```
~$ egrep '\sA\s' filename
   A  
 A
```

Comment: it displays nothing for me according to the op's input.

Comment: @AvinashRaj OP clearly wants "surrounded by white space on both sides". The input in the question is probably incorrect.